# Sbt update shows Server access Error: java.security.ProviderException: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: java, scala, sbt

Yesterday everything was working fine, but today when I execute `sbt update` I am getting:

```
[info] Resolving org.log4s#log4s_2.11;latest.release ...
[error] Server access Error: java.security.ProviderException: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/log4s/log4s_2.11/maven-metadata.xml
[error] Server access Error: java.security.ProviderException: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/log4s/log4s_2.11/
[warn]  module not found: org.log4s#log4s_2.11;latest.release
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/hkr/.ivy2/local/org.log4s/log4s_2.11/[revision]/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/log4s/log4s_2.11/[revision]/log4s_2.11-[revision].pom
[info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;latest.release ...
[error] Server access Error: java.security.ProviderException: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/maven-metadata.xml
[error] Server access Error: java.security.ProviderException: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/
```

For all my dependencies, searhing I've found some answers pointing that may be was the CA Java certificates, but I have them installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's finally working, I had to update `Scala` to version `2.12.1` and remove `openjdk` (Icedtea in Gentoo) and install `oracle-jdk`.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue and for me changing the JDK from OpenJDK to OracleJDK worked. I have Fedora and SBT taken from here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html

So there is no need for upgrading Scala version, especially because not every library is upgraded right now.

Comment: Yes, I think what did the trick for me was also the change from OpenJDK to OracleJDK. Regards